# CollectionView Xamarin not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView and a CollectionView (Xam 4 pre-8 ). I added the ListView is to prove items show. The binding appears correctly and I have added Xam 4 to all of the projects. CollectionView does not appear. Why?

AppDelegate:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Content Page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:RecipeTonight.Mobile.ViewModels"
         x:Class="RecipeTonight.Mobile.Views.WelcomePage"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"

         >
<ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Margin="20"
        BackgroundColor="#e9e9e9"

        >
        <Label Text="Hello World" />
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Test"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="40">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

On the screen I see [image: Simulator iOS]

Comment: try assigning a height.

Comment: @Jason awesome thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

@Jason was correct. Set the height

Comment: the height of what?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had misspelled the names of the properties (i.e. I had used all capitalized property names). Unlike ListView, CollectionView doesn't have lines between items to tell you something is there.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was more generic, but this was the first page I found when searching for help so perhaps my solution will be of use to somebody:

Don't forget to set your ItemSource to public in the code-behind.

i.e.

```
//XAML

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}" >
     ...etc



//C#

public List<RecipeItem> RecipeList {get; set;} // <---- PUBLIC!
```